# NodeJS Puppeteer "ReferenceError: page is not defined"

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I've encountered a problem related to this specific piece of code :

```
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(arr[0]["link"]);
    sleep(5000);
    const claim = await page.evaluate(() => {
```

It sends me this error (last line on top is the line 23) :

```
C:\Users\root\Documents\Workspace\NodeJS Scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221
            throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
                  ^

Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: page is not defined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:4:13
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\Users\root\Documents\Workspace\NodeJS Scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\Users\root\Documents\Workspace\NodeJS Scrapper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
    at async C:\Users\root\Documents\Workspace\NodeJS Scrapper\part2.js:23:19
```

There is my complete code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
        currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

const fs = require('fs');
const data = fs.readFileSync('./games.txt', 'utf8');
const arr = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(arr);

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(arr[0]["link"]);
    sleep(5000);
    
    const claim = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let claim = [];
        if(document.querySelector('div.css-xvql1u button.css-n9sjaa span').textContent == "Continuer") {
            page.click("div.css-xvql1u button.css-n9sjaa");
        }
        sleep(15000);
        return claim;
    });
    await browser.close();
    console.log(claim);
})();
```

And the file "games.txt" contains this array :

```
[{"title":"Mages of Mystralia","link":"https://www.epicgames.com/store/fr/p/mages-of-mystralia"}]
```

Can you help me to solve this issue please ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working/complete snippet.

Comment: This is now my complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the issue is on the line:

```
page.click("div.css-xvql1u button.css-n9sjaa");
```

`page.evaluate` runs the function you provide in the webpage's context. (meaning the variable `page` from the closure above isn't defined.)

You should instead replace that line with something like the following:

```
document.querySelector("div.css-xvql1u button.css-n9sjaa").click()
```

---

Alternatively, if you really insist on using the `page` identifier or any other value from your puppeteer script, you may pass it as an argument to the function. ([check here for an example](https://pptr.dev/#?show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args))